# $_post function seems not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

```
<?php require 'db_connect.php'; ?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="register.php" >
  Username :
  <input type="text" id="username" class="username" name="username" value="">
  <br>
  Password :
  <input type="password" id="password" class="password" name="password" value="">
  <br>
  Confirm Password :
  <input type="password" id="con_password" class="con_password" name="con_password" value="">
  <br>
  Phone No. :
  <input type="text" id="phoneno" class="phoneno" name="phoneno" value="">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Register">
</form>
<?php
 if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
$res = "insert into register(username, password, phoneno) value('".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."','".$_POST["phoneno"]."')";
mysqli_query($conn, $res);
if(!empty($_POST)){
echo "Registered!";
}
else {
echo "Try Again!";
}
}
?>
```

I want to check all $_Post fields check for empty, null or 0 if values of form is not filled show error "try again" and filled show error "registered"? please tell me first is this function is correct or not. if not correct what the correct function.

Comment: Then check! Do you want to know how to check?

Comment: Right now, any *crap* in `$_POST` is enough to be considered valid.

Comment: yes, dough65536  I want to know how to check through php

Comment: You should stop working with SQL completely until you understand SQL injection exploits. **You have an enormous security hole**. The server blindly puts all of those post parameters in the sql, and runs it. Use parameter binding for queries.

Comment: Please [read about SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: You don't solve anything by "checking", you make your code handle all possible (and even barely possible) inputs. *Then* callers that have a UI can show something reasonable based on a catch-all generic `500 Failed` error returned from the server. Don't help the attacker.

Comment: Actually, dough65536 my client wants to check or validate data through php functions.

Comment: First "checking" or "validating" is the worst possible implementation. First you make the SQL operation securely pass thorough absolutely arbitrary information without any possibility of a SQL injection exploit, *then* you make the server do common sense checks before the database operation. If you have the worst possible SQL code then you can't add a layer of sugar on top of it and expect that to be a real implementation. You must fix your completely insecure SQL code first.

Comment: It is not even a big change, use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [PDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement#PHP_PDO), for example

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate fields through php, you have to check each field individually. There are some checks you can apply on a data.

```
if ($_POST['field'] === null) //I would suggest === because it will return false if $_POST['field'] is 0 or empty string
if (empty($_POST['field'])) //to check empty data 
if (isset($_POST['field'])) //to check if data exists
```

If you want to validate your fields like is either string? or digits? or alpha numeric? or all lowercase? or uppercase? There are certain functions which allows you to check field by just calling a single function

Please have a look at this page: [CType Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php)

You can also use this option. Make all fields **required** you want to check null or 0, this will make sure that data in field is must before submitting form.
Try changing input field from:

```
<input type="text" id="username" class="username" name="username" value="">
```

to:

```
<input type="text" id="username" class="username" name="username" value="" required >
```

Also as Rishi said you should also edit query, change **values** to **values**

Also 1 tip, you are inserting data in database first and then validating data, according to me it is not good practice, you should first validate data then if all went good then insert it into database, else you will add bad data in database also.

Your final code will be:

```
<?php require 'db_connect.php'; ?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="register.php" >
    Username :
    <input type="text" id="username" class="username" name="username" required >
    <br>
    Password :
    <input type="password" id="password" class="password" name="password" required >
    <br>
    Confirm Password :
    <input type="password" id="con_password" class="con_password" name="con_password" required >
    <br>
    Phone No. :
    <input type="text" id="phoneno" class="phoneno" name="phoneno" required >
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Register">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $res = "insert into register(username, password, phoneno) values('".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."','".$_POST["phoneno"]."')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $res);
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks rishi & sayed for your help but I want to check or validate data through php